# workspaces internal error when running "yarn dev"

Tags: reactjs, vite, yarnpkg-v2

I have a project I cloned from GitHub that was created in Vite+react+tailwind

When I run “yarn dev” I receive the following error

> Internal Error: PROJECTNAME@workspace:.: This package doesn't seem to be present in your lockfile; run "yarn install" to update the lockfile 
> at AF.getCandidates (/Users/name/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.1.1.cjs:437:4421) 
> at pd.getCandidates (/Users/name/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.1.1.cjs:432:5275) 
> at /Users/name/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.1.1.cjs:441:7674 
> at du (/Users/name/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.1.1.cjs:382:4003) 
> at R (/Users/name/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.1.1.cjs:441:7654)

Then, when I run “yarn install” here is what I get

> ➤ YN0000: ┌ Resolution step
> ➤ YN0035: │ @noirgallery/restless@npm:^0.7.0: The remote server failed to provide the requested resource
> ➤ YN0035: │   Response Code: 404 (Not Found)
> ➤ YN0035: │   Request Method: GET
> ➤ YN0035: │   Request URL: https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@noirgallery%2frestless
> ➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 0s 670ms
> ➤ YN0000: Failed with errors in 0s 675ms
> ➤ YN0032: fsevents@npm:2.3.2: Implicit dependencies on node-gyp are discouraged
> ➤ YN0061: sane@npm:4.1.0 is deprecated: some dependency vulnerabilities fixed, support for node < 10 dropped, and newer ECMAScript syntax/features added
> ➤ YN0061: resolve-url@npm:0.2.1 is deprecated: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
> ➤ YN0061: urix@npm:0.1.0 is deprecated: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
> ➤ YN0061: core-js@npm:1.2.7 is deprecated: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.

And then if I run “yarn dev” again, this just repeats.